# conditional probability maybe?

Tags: probability

If in application A, 70% of the users are men and 30% women.
In application B, 60% men and 40% women.
Given you have both applications, what is the probability that you are a man?

Comment: Are you assuming that prior to any knowledge of applications, there is a 50% chance that you're a man?

Comment: lets say that men and women are 50-50

Comment: and i am only looking at those that use both applications

Answer (score 1):

P(man and both apps|both apps)=P(man and both apps)/P(both apps)

Comment: can't i get any estimation?

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ stand for "is a man" and $W$ for "is a woman", and A and B for "uses application A" or B, respectively. Then we know:

$P(M|A)=0.7,P(W|A)=0.3,P(M|B)=0.6,P(W|B)=0.4$

However, you want to know $P(M|A\cap B)=\frac{P(M\cap A \cap B)}{P(A\cap B)}$

Unfortunately, you don't know $P(A\cap B)$ nor the fraction of "dual users" that are men. The stated information is irrelevant to the question you want to answer.